# How to stop the browser from running the script as soon as as the page gets loaded?

Tags: javascript

To keep the browser from executing the script as soon as as the page gets loaded, what must the script be written as ?

This is one of the questions which is beguiling me and I am not understanding what this means or what is the solution to it .

Does any one know what is the solution to this question ?

Comment: Whitch sort of script ? PHP, JS ?

Comment: If you don't want to run the script when the page loads, when do you want it to run?

Comment: The question is tagged as `javascript` mate. It is js script that i  am talking about .

Comment: You mean you want to load all the DOM elements before running the script?Put it after </body> then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give too many details, but I think you should put your script into a function. Then you can call it when you want it to run and it doesn't automatically start on page load.

Comment: Thanks  a lot.. You are quite right , Will accept it once stack lets me .